# changing size of image inside ImageButton

Tags: android, image, imageview, imagebutton

I have an ImageView and ImageButton. I croped my source image using bitmap and its size has changed so i used this code for my ImageView to enlarge the image inside it:

```
LayoutParams params1 = new LayoutParams((int) (320.0f * scale), (int) (250.0f * scale));
ImgView.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

but this doesn't work for ImageButton(it only enlarges button ,not image). Please help to enlarge image inside button.

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code:

**android:scaleType="fitCenter"** is use to scale the android images.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_topleft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```